# Unparseable Number in Google Analytics Talend Pull

Tags: java, google-analytics, etl, talend, unparseable

I'm using the tGoogleAnalyticsInput component to extract some basic Google Analytics dimensions and metrics and write them to a sql database.

However, I keep getting a java error when it tries to pull the source "(direct)" it flags it as an unparseable number. Everywhere in my ETL I have the source set as a string, so I'm not sure what's tripping it up. Attached are some relevant screenshots:

tGoogleAnalyticsInput component setup:
[image: tGoogleAnalyticsInput component setup]

Schema with everything but sessions as a string:
[image: Schema with everything but sessions as a string]

And here is the specific language of the error:

```
Exception in component tGoogleAnalyticsInput_1
java.lang.Exception: Convert field: row1.gasessions value=[(direct)] countLines=1 failed:Unparseable number: "(direct)"
```

Ideally it should output the dimensions and metrics to the table for a single day specified by the context.

Answer (score 0):

The schema you defined seems to be wrong. According [to this tutorial](http://community.jaspersoft.com/blog/using-tgoogleanalyticsinput-jasperetltalend) the schema in their case looks like:

- source (String)
- medium (String)
- date (Date)
- visits (String)
- continent (String)

Your first column is `Sessions (Integer)`. Since a number conversion error is thrown I suppose this is the culprit. Try changing the type to `String`.

Also I am not sure if the `Metrics` entries come first in the response or last. You might want to change all data types to `String` to be able to consume the data and analyze it and later change data types accordingly.